# Azure DevOps Dashboard: How to establish connection between widgets Query Title, and Query Results/Query Charts?

Tags: azure-devops, widget, dashboard, interactive

I want to establish connection between widgets, e.g., when I click on query title the result should update in Query Result (widget) according to the title selected. Could you please suggest a way to achieve the result?

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Dtd1.png)